# Play unity web game without downloading unity web player

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I'm hosting a Unity Web Game with my Google Drive and would like to share it with my friends. I tried to launch it on a different PC and instead of the game launching, a message told me to download Unity Web Player. Is there a way in which I can bundle the player with my game? Is there a way in which I can host the player with my game? Is there a way in which I can let users play my game without them downloading or installing anything?

Comment: -1 for not being a programming question.  But no, you can't.  The unity web player is required on a client machine to play unity web games.

Comment: Just like to agree with Archer in saying that this isn't a programming question and shouldn't be here. But you will need to wait until Unity 5 where they are introducing WebGL exporting. This may be out towards the end of the year or early 2015.

Comment: +1 because I like new users, even if they dont know the rules yet

Comment: +1 because I think its a valid question and I hate when people get picky on here :)

Comment: +1 because it answers my question and could be easily worded so that it "counts" as programming question

Answer (score 2):

Unity 5 added support for building `WebGL` apps which essentially convert all code to `javascript` and can be used without the need to explicitly download `Unity webplayer` by the user.

you can find more about this on [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html)